# MySQL cannot create alter procedures anymore(superuser needed)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Suddenly I cannot create any stored procedures. I cannot even alter the ones I created with the same user. I have not made any changes with mysql or any settings. I am using Workbench. Database is on siteground hosting. The user has all the privileges possible. Was everything working perfect about a week ago, and now its giving me error: "Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation    0.093 sec"
Is there a way to fix this via workbench or cpanel?

Comment: *"Is there a way to fix this via workbench or cpanel?"* Because you said cpanel i advice your to contact your webhoster..

Comment: Do you know which MySQL version they are running?

Comment: I already did, they said its beyond their scope. As I understand I have no access to main console when DB is on hosting?

Comment: *"I already did, they said its beyond they scope"* Beyond they scope? That's a wierd answer from a webhosting provider

Comment: Server version: 5.6.40-84.0-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.0, Revision 47234b3 cpsrvd 11.66.0.24
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
PHP extension: mysqliDokumentacija curlDokumentacija mbstringDokumentacija
PHP version: 5.6.30

Comment: MySQL 5.6 manual... *"By default, MySQL automatically grants the ALTER ROUTINE and EXECUTE privileges to the routine creator. This behavior can be changed by disabling the automatic_sp_privileges system variable"* i have a feeling this setting is 0 on there server check it which `SELECT @@automatic_sp_privileges` if that value is 0 that would explain it..

Comment: The SELECT @@automatic_sp_privileges returned 1. When I select right click on procedure and click alter nothing opens, also I cannot create. I think this is not normal since I have created 9 procedures and was able to edit them a while ago :(

Comment: If you don't have access to the mysql settings and no changes have been done by you, you should contact your hosting provider again. Maybe you had bad luck with your first contact and someone who does not really know what's going on was on the phone though.

Comment: I will definately try that, because I dont have any acces to mysql server it self